# Trouble positioning footer under main content

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm trying to create my website from scratch, and facing quite a few problems along the way..
The most recent problem being that I can't manage to get my footer positioned after the `main-wrapper` div. The most obvious reason why I'm encountering this problem is because `main-wrapper` contains elements which are absolutely positioned and so its height doesn't adjust accordingly.
I searched all over the place before asking and I even implemented a clearfix to no result..

The page is [here](http://clarkewing.byethost.com/template/)

I also created a Plunk with all the files [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/awOPtbGneoydAfYKthLD)

Comment: Hi, do you want a sticky footer? Then have a look at http://www.cssstickyfooter.com

Comment: how about taking footer outside of main-wrapper?

Comment: I wasn't exactly looking to create a sticky footer. My problem was that I wanted to position my footer automatically right under the main-wrapper. I ultimately decided to go the easy route though and simply change the height of the main-wrapper manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using css it will be very difficult,
you can try using this script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementsByClassName('main-wrapper')[0].style.height = document.getElementsByClassName('hero-bg')[0].offsetHeight+"px";
 </script>
```

put this just below of closing of "main-wrapper" section

Answer (score 0):

what about adding this to your css #footer:

```
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 0;
```

( if you want the footer to get pushed down the page if there is more content in content, this want work )

Comment: I just added it to the code on the site, but as you might notice, it's not exactly doing what I'd like it to do..

Comment: The problem is that it also messes up what's going on with the divs inside the #globalfooter

Comment: your clear:both is at the wrong place that's may why it messes up. what do you want it to do when you resize the broswer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to your footer css style,

```
#globalfooter{
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0px; 
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's what @caramba just suggested, but it's not really doing what I'd like. I updated the code on the testing server (which I linked in the question) but look at what happens when you resize the browser window..